# How To Get Xcode Interface Builder To Pop Up When I Click My NIB File?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

I am at work and trying to make an application for my company in Xcode, however when I click the Nib file I cannot get the interface builder to pop up. I am on a Mac that has lockdown control on it, and I am wondering if this is affecting my development environment? When I double-click the Nib file nothing happens. It just modals the normal Xcode window. Am I at a loss on this? I am wondering if I am going to have to develop this application away from my work?

Comment: Have you checked to see if Xcode (or IB) is logging anything? Look in /Applications/Utilities/Console.app.

Comment: Does IB even exist on this Mac? Check /Developer/Applications; it should be in there.

Answer (score 1):

I only know that when the file is open with Xcode you must add the quarts composer framework
You can do this going to build phases, frameworks and add

Answer (score 0):

When you make a right-click (ctrl-click) on the file and move to `open with` is there a link to interface builder? If so you can select the preferred program for all .nib files with 
`*right-click* > information` on a .nib file.

Comment: No, unfortunately not :(. I think I am out of luck.

Comment: Hmm...maybe you can select interface builder with `right-click > information > open with (dropdown menu) and select "another program"`